# Offsetting background while keeping it responsive

Tags: css

I am trying to combine three things:

- Gradient background
- Offset background
- Background image

I essentially want to achieve exactly what I have in my JSFiddle below, but with the gradient following no matter what size.

https://jsfiddle.net/023hqb6w/

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url("https://c.tadst.com/gfx/750w/sunrise-sunset-sun-calculator.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% calc(50% - 150px);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

How do I do that?

Comment: making -  background-position: 100%;  will work

Comment: @PraveenPoonia Nope and not the same effect as `cover`.

Comment: try to specify position and size for each image individually like:    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url("https://c.tadst.com/gfx/750w/sunrise-sunset-sun-calculator.jpg");
    background-size: auto, cover;
    background-position: 50% calc(50% - 150px), 0 0;